# ActionListener and JChechkBox

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I'm having a hard time to put action listeners on multiple check boxes, that  are on a panel and bordered.
Like for example : if a checkbox is selected,than it must update an int, in my case that is total, and if more than one is selected the total must be updated.
This is what I'm doing :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
    if (hat.isSelected()) {
        total += 50;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error, 
One more question, how do I make it so that I can put multiple item listeners in a class.
P.s : I'm a beginner at coding GUI-s in Java.
Help would be very appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Projekt.actionPerformed(Projekt.java:61)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
```

Edit : Added Error Codes

Comment: *But I'm getting an error*, Exactly which error do you get?

Comment: at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
there are some more lines, that I didn't copy here

Comment: The two line of the exception are probably the most important, they describe the error and the location.  Add, at least, the first two lines

Comment: @MadProgrammer oh, sorry    
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Projekt.actionPerformed(Projekt.java:61)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please add this info as formatted text *within* your question, not as comment.

Comment: Okay, guess time.  `hat` is probably `null` because it's never initialised. This could be because you forget or because you  are shadowing your variables. Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be impossible to provide you with any more guidance

Comment: The exception stack trace tells you: The NullPointerException happened in line 61 of your file `Projekt.java`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer hat is JCheckBox, if it is selected total += 50

Comment: @KobraCode Irrelevant - if you've not initialised or you've shadowed an instance field, then it will be `null`, hence your error. The diagnostics of `NullPointerException` are almost always the same. You need to work you way backwards through your code and find out why the variable is not been assigned a value

Comment: @MadProgrammer I managed to fix the error code, but now when the checkbox is selected it does not update the total, the checkbox and the total is a field variable, and the total is initialized to 0 . I do really appreciate your help, thanks a lot !